# How to run a docker container as a daemon starting the rails project built inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I've built an image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM rails

RUN apt-get update
RUN mkdir /home/projects
WORKDIR /home/projects

RUN rails new hello

EXPOSE 3000
```

And this command:

```
sudo docker build -t="hello" .
```

Now my question is how to get the container running as a daemon and with the `rails server` command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a default command with a Dockerfile, you can use CMD:

`CMD /bin/rails server`

This will run `bash -c /bin/rails server`.  You can also do

`CMD ["/bin/rails", "server"]` which avoids the bash parent process.

(I'm not familiar with rails, but you get the idea.)

You can also use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` which has various differences from CMD, such as how you can pass arguments to the main command.

`docker run -d hello` will run the container as a daemon.

Comment: Thanks that works now. And to find the right path I used : `which rails` /usr/local/bin/rails